# consistent numbering across word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a math textbook in word 2003

I have numbered exercices interspersed with text. I'd like the numbers to grow sequentially, in the usual fashion: an addition in the middle of the list makes all numbers after it grow by one automatically, even if there is text in between.

Can it be done ? How ?

Answer (score 3):

You'll find instructions for creating numbered equations [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7168046_number-equations-word-2007.html) for Word 2007 that worked for me.  The basic idea is to make each equation a separate paragraph, turn on numbering for those equation paragraphs and mark that the numbering continues from the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered it is trivial to do so with mathtype (a proprietary and paid software that adds math capabilities for Word)

if you have it, just go to the mathtype menu, and "insert number". Some convenient numbering options are available